# "How to change the keyword color in R studio?"

Tags: r, fonts, rstudio

I would like to change the font colors in Rstudio, I Know how to change the Rstudio Appearance under Global options

I have tried to change the Rstudio Appearance, its working but i want to change the Keywords colors

Tried:
Tools> global options> apprearance

Please help me to change the font or Keyword color in RStudio

Comment: Are you asking about syntax highlighting? This should be what you are looking for: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200549016-Customizing-RStudio. If you can't do what you want with this information you need to customize the `.css` file that defines the theme.

Comment: Claudiu Papasteri, Thanks for your information. Could you pls guide me to edit .css